# Converting int to toString() method

Tags: class, methods, type-conversion, tostring

Hello I am new to coding and am working on designing my own class, which computes the average of 'n' numbers which will be provided in the driver program as an array. Currently I continue to get an error "incompatible types, cannot convert int to java.lang.String" in my toString method at the end and am not sure how to get solve it. any help is appreciated.

```
//this code computes the average 
public int adverage(int...array)
    {
       int adverage = 0;
       if (array.length > 0)
       {
           int sum = 0;
           for(int num : array)
                sum = sum + num; //add numbers in array 
           adverage = (int)sum / array.length; //divide numbers in     array by the array lenth

        }

       return adverage;
    }


 //this code is the toString return method
 public String toString()
    {

        return getMinimun() + getMaximun() + adverage();

    }
```

It is merely a requirement of the problem I am working on the the final result be displayed at a string. Thankyou!

Answer (score 2):

According to your function definition,

```
public String toString()
```

this function must return a String. However, in your implementation, you seem to be returning an int.

Wrapping your return value in String.valueOf should do the trick.

```
return String.valueOf(getMinimun() + getMaximun() + adverage());
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that in the toString() method you are returning integers instead of strings. I get the total of those integers if that's what you're trying to do as a number and then convert it into a string.

```
public String toString()
{
    int total = getMaximun() + getMinimun() + adverage();
    String done = Integer.toString(total);

    return done;
}
```

If that makes sense.